# Yii-2 app in subfolder on Google App Engine gives error 404

Tags: google-app-engine, yii2

I have yii-2 application running on gae with the following structure:

```
- root
    - src
        - config
        - controllers
        - models
        - views
        ...
    - subfolder-src
        - config
        - controllers
        - models
        - views
        ...
    - vendor
    - web
        - css
        - js
        - subfolder
            - css
            - js
            - index.php
        - index.php
        ...
```

Basically, it's two projects with separate MVC sharing same vendor (kind of yii-2 advanced template).

If I go to `mydomain.com`, `mydomain.com/site/login`...and so on, everything is working fine. Even when I go to `mydomain.com/subfolder/` the home page of "subfolder" is shown as expected.
But when I'll try to reach some `controller/action` within `subfolder`, all I get is 404 - Not found.

What I noticed is that this happens only when I turn on prettyUrl. `mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php?r=controller%2Faction` is working correctly too.

My guess is that either my `app.yaml` handlers are wrong or I'm missing something in urlManager config.

This is my app.yaml

```
service: default
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
  composer_flags: --no-scripts --dev --prefer-dist


handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: static/assets
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: It seems it might be a problem because you do not have a handler with a pattern matching the sub folder path.

You can see here (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example) even if it's for PHP how can you make a pattern that would achieve the results you are trying to get.